# Derivative from Graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

Hi, I am trying to study a bit ahead for my calculus class next year and I came across this question. I was wondering how to find the derivative of the graph without the function. 
I figured I could try by finding the critical points at the local extrema. The local extrema are at -2, -1, 0, and 1, so f'(x) = x(x+2)(x+1)(x-1). Then if I integrate that, that would be the function below, but it doesn't look like the one below when I followed those steps. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: See what happens when you integrate f'(x) = -x(x+2)(x+1)(x-1). It will look like [this.](http://imgur.com/PtRrC3n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not be surprised if the question was asking you to *draw a rough graph* of $f'(x)$, and for this you do not need a formula.  All you need to say is that $f'(x)$ is negative when $x<-2$, zero when $x=2$, positive when $-2<x<-1$ and so on.

---

If you do want a formula, your $f'(x)=x(x+2)(x+1)(x-1)$ is one possibility for the derivative of a function  with the given local extrema, but by no means the only one.  A simple extension is that it might be
$$f'(x)=cx(x+2)(x+1)(x-1)\ ,\tag{$*$}$$
where $c$ is a constant, as this will still have the same zeros.  In fact, the graph tells you a bit more about $f'(x)$.  You can see from the graph that if $x$ is large in either the positive or negative directions, $f(x)$ is decreasing and so the derivative should be negative.  However,
$$x(x+2)(x+1)(x-1)$$
is positive if $x$ is large and so this is not right.  The simplest solution is to take $(*)$ with a negative constant $c$, for example,
$$f'(x)=-x(x+2)(x+1)(x-1)\ .$$
But in fact there are still many further possibilities.  You don't actually need a factor of $x$ in the derivative, you just need something which is zero when $x=0$.  Another example would be $e^x-1$.  Another example again would be $\sin x$, but if you think a bit further this actually doesn't work since you would then have $f'(\pi)=0$ which you don't want.  The same goes for the zeros at $-2,-1$ and $1$.  So here is another possible answer:
$$f'(x)=-(e^x-1)(2(x+2)+\sin(x+2))(x^2-1)^3\ .$$
All of these complications will affect the graph of $f(x)$ in various ways, but since you are only given a rough graph anyway, it may not be possible to tell the difference.